# sizeof over a function type; gcc doesn't recognized it as ill-formed

Tags: c++, function, sizeof

Doing this little test (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71096660a727f4b0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << sizeof(void()) << '\n';
}
```

`gcc` yields a warning instead of an error (and prints 1). Shouldn't that be treated as an ill-formed expression as clang does?

Comment: Diagnostic-ed in both cases.

Comment: @Jarod42 In which gcc version? I've just find out that up to version g++-7, you have to enable -pedantic-errors to issue an error. If -pedantic-errors is disabled, then it issues a warning. I don't know what happens in gcc version > 7.

Comment: I mean, (as in the answer), that warning is a valid diagnostic.

Comment: This is a [documented GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard doesn't discriminate between a warning and error. So, an ill-formed construct can have a warning emitted only. It is not a requirement that compilation should fail also. The only requirement is that diagnostics should be issued. The exact meaning of diagnostics is not specified.

(And a related note: there are some constructs, which are ill-formed, but no diagnostics required at all by the standard)

Comment: Mmmm, so how can I be sure that these kind of ill-formed but not diagnosed constructs will have a portable behaviour on SFINAE overloads? Because my problem is that I'm trying to create a check (C++03) to know if something is a function type by forcing that some type is not void or an object (because sizeof is not defined and it's not a reference)

Comment: @Peregring-lk: Maybe you should ask this specific question (so we know the exact details. This is needed, because, for example, at deduction, function types decay to function pointers). But maybe you can achieve what you want with explicit specialization for function types, instead of relying on sizeof().

Comment: The problem is that I'm restricted to C++03, so I cannot specialize for functions because the number of parameters could be unknown and I cannot use variadic templates (unless I create specializations for up-to 8 or 10 parameters or some big amount). I'm thinking to create a question specific for that purpose.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: maybe `-Werror=pointer-arith` can solve your problem?

Comment: It's not gcc related, it's about portability. But I have just now change the strategy and now detect if T is a function by discard: if it's not a fundamental type, a reference or an object.